# How to download a Gif from internet and save it into the app directory - android

Tags: android, android-studio, gif

I have a list of URLs, i need to download all Gifs from those URLs and save it into app directory, and then show it in GifView. How can I do it?

Any help is very appreciated

Comment: 1/ download a file 2/ save a file in the app directory 3/ load a file into GifView. Which of those 3 is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) library. Well documented

Answer (score 0):

use [UIL(Universal Image Loader)](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader) for more customization image loader.

for UIL setup [here](https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader/wiki/Quick-Setup)